# can we move molecules in solids or surfaces via applying voltage?

Tags: molecules

Is it possible to have movement of molecules/atoms in a solid, under electric field? Similar to the movement of electrons under electric potential difference? I was thinking if this can happened to adsorbed molecules in solid surfaces. Can we apply voltage and move these molecules? Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Lithium diffusion in silicon is strongly enhanced by imposing an electric field. So, yes.

Comment: interesting to know, thanks, are we talking about solid silicon?

Answer (score 0):

Molecules do have a charge and this can be exploited to move them or separated them (see [electrophoresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophoresis)).
That is usually done in a gel rather than a solid so that molecules can move more freely. Yet in principle you could do that in a solid too, but I guess it would take a longer and a higher voltage. It all depends on how bound the molecule/atom you are trying to move is to the solide..